# Is it possible to integrate the AWS cognito hosted UI with the Amazon Pinpoint for analytics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint

We are looking for a way to integrate the **AWS Cognito hosted UI** with the **Amazon Pinpoint** for analytics. We have also set up the Pinpoint for Cognito with the corresponding region, but nothing shows up in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an integration present for AWS congnito and Pinpoint.
Although, your question is a little bit vague. Because you have not added other details.
Till which part you are done.
Still, let me add some some steps, let's see if it helps you.

One possible reason could be wrong mapping of regions in aws.
Please use this link to check mapping:
[AWS Region mapping for cognito and Pinpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-pinpoint-integration.html)

Sign in to the Amazon Cognito console

.

In the navigation pane, Manage User Pools, and choose the user pool you want to edit.

1. Choose the Analytics tab.
2. Choose Add analytics and campaigns.
3. Choose a Cognito app client from the list.
4. To map your Amazon Cognito app to an Amazon Pinpoint project, choose
   the Amazon Pinpoint project from the list.
5. Choose Share user attribute data with Amazon Pinpoint if you want Amazon Cognito to send email addresses and phone numbers to Amazon Pinpoint in order to create additional endpoints for users.

Comment: Hi Anuj, I have already mentioned that we have correctly mapped the region. We have already followed these steps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-pinpoint-integration.html
Thank you for your answer anyway.